# PHPMailer SMTP error returned

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I've taken over the development of my company's website and there is a password reset form that doesn't work and I cannot figure it out. It uses PHPMailer to send a reset key to the users email address. The php query's the database ok and returns the correct email address for the user and the reset key.

```
<?php
require_once('./library.php');
require_once('./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$Trader = new CompanyTrader();

$resetdata = $Trader->resetTrader($_GET['name']);
print_arr($resetdata);

    $reset = new PHPMailer(true);
    $reset->IsSMTP();

    try {
            $reset->Host = EM_HOST;
            $reset->SMTPDebug = 2; //2 to debug
            $reset->SMTPAuth = EM_AUTH;
            $reset->AddReplyTo(CONFIRM_REPLY_EMAIL, 'Company');
            $reset->AddAddress($resetdata['traders_email_add'], $resetdata['traders_cont_name']);
            $reset->SetFrom(CONFIRM_REPLY_EMAIL, 'Company');
            $reset->Subject = 'Company Account Password Reset';
            $reset->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
            $body = file_get_contents('./templates/reset_email.html');
            $body = eregi_replace("\[USER_NAME\]", $resetdata['traders_user_name'], $body);
            $body = eregi_replace("\[RESET_KEY\]", $resetdata['traders_reset'], $body);
            $reset->MsgHTML($body);
            $reset->Send();
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            @log_this("Pass Reset Sending Failed: ".$e->errorMessage(),"email");
            return false;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            @log_this("Pass Reset Sending Failed: ".$e->getMessage(),"email");
            return false;
    }
?>
```

PHPMailer returns an error as follows

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-78.109.170.70.srvlist.ukfast.net ESMTP Exim 4.80 #2 Wed, 26 Dec 2012 21:41:58 +0000 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail. 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-78.109.170.70.srvlist.ukfast.net Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK id=1Tnyje-0000Kh-IL
```

I cant work it out. Is it because the host has caped the amount of emails we can send? If so, all the other PHPMailer forms work and all the settings are the same throughout the site. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any Errors in the resulting SMTP. PHPMailer is opening the connection and getting all the way through the point of sending data via the `DATA` command and appears to send it. The `250 OK id=1Tnyje-0000Kh-IL` Tells you that the mail server accepted the message and gave it a ID of 1Tnyje-0000Kh-IL. YOu should review the SMTP Logs of your mail server to track the message.

Comment: okay. thanks. silly me. just noticed this has been going into my spam folder. how can i avoid this?

Comment: Does your reverse DNS match your IP address? Many mail servers check this in order to determine if mail is from a SPAM sender or not. Also check that your IP address is not on email blacklists.

Comment: Review the Complete Headers of the message. You can also review your SPF Record for the sites domain. If your SPF does not include the server that relays mail for your site, this might increase the SPAM Score, it might look like Spoof'd mail. Contact your mail provider and ask them for further support if this does not get you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the SMTP Info you provided, the messages show that they are relaying. Check your SPAM Folder or with your mail provider to track the messages.

Comment: @Niby This was not an error. It's just the SMTP banner. After DATA do you see a 250?

Comment: @Niby How exactly...?

Comment: @AnnaOleksiuk are you having a similar problem?

Comment: @AnnaOleksiuk try changing your mail body content to simple text.

Comment: @Twisty Meanwhile i called to his hosting service provider and they said, that e-mail has arrived correctly, so they don't know my receiver is claiming different :/ Thanks for response, tho.